# IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "class" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: id, category'

Tags: java, python, indexing, pyspark

the code i used  is

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'class', outputCol = 'classIndex')
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)

indexed.show()
```

and i am getting the following error

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
 77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
 78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
 80             raise
 81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "class" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: id, category'
```

how to fix it??

Comment: Where is the Java code?

Comment: it was a part of python code for ml pipelining which i am executing in google colab i did not do any code in java for it